# why prefering @TestConfiguration than @Configuration in src/test

Tags: spring, testing, spring-annotations

i currently study more in deep the @TestConfiguration
and i wonder why using this combo..

```
@TestConfiguration
public class TestConfig {
    
    // some bean definitions
```

and then using

```
@SpringBootTest
@Import(TestConfig.class)
class UsingImport {

@Autowired
ConfigBean configBean;

// some code
```

and not using the classic @Configuration, in the src/test,
as it is totally legal do it.
Why is the real purpose of @TestConfiguration, as we can do the same with @Configuration ?

Am i wrong ?

Answer (score 0):

The key difference between `@TestConfiguration` and regular `@Configuration` is that the classes marked with the usual `@Configuration` annotation are included in the application context automatically because scanning recognises this annotation. Whereas classes labelled with `@TestConfiguration` are not subject to scanning, and you will have to import the configuration for each test manually, giving you the flexibility to control the number of beans needed for that test

Comment: i made a test but it seems it's not right : i used a bean from a @TestConfiguration and it was used as injection, but at the same time, i could use a bean from the default configuration (annoted by @Configuration). So, it seems that the default application context is effectively raised. Pehraps there is something i don't understand, or an option i miss..

Comment: Try looking here https://reflectoring.io/spring-boot-testconfiguration/
I apologise for misinforming you, the overall context of the application is still raised. Edited reply

Answer (score 0):

[`@TestConfiguration`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/api/org/springframework/boot/test/context/TestConfiguration.html):

> [`@Configuration`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/context/annotation/Configuration.html) that can be used to define additional beans or customizations for a test. Unlike regular `@Configuration` classes the use of `@TestConfiguration` does not prevent auto-detection of [`@SpringBootConfiguration`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/api/org/springframework/boot/SpringBootConfiguration.html).

Comment: so, the only purpose of @TestConfiguration, for the other which do not use/import it, to not scan the declarations of the beans which are inside . that's all ?